# In Queue Using Typedef Struct More Than One?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, queue

I don't understand what is the purpose of that. I saw this from my professor code. Why is he declaring one struct in another structure?

```
typedef struct{
    char name[30];
}element;

typedef struct{
    element queue_ele[MAX_SIZE];
    int rear;
    int front;
}queue;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant you could have something like this instead:

```
typedef struct{
    char queue_ele[MAX_SIZE][30];
    int rear;
    int front;
}queue;
```

This is of course possible, but think about an element structure with two members in it:

```
typedef struct{
    char name[30];
    char address[60];
}element;
```

This can also be "unrolled" into the `queue` structure:

```
typedef struct{
    char queue_names[MAX_SIZE][30];
    char queue_addresses[MAX_SIZE][60];
    int rear;
    int front;
}queue;
```

But think if you have even *more* members of the `element` structure? That would make the `queue` structure larger and add more complexity to it.

Even though there is some debate if "single array of structures" is better, or "multiple arrays of individual values", for complex structure the former (single array of structures) is better in my opinion.